# How do i change the intellisense settings in VS2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

What the title says. Is there a way to change intellisense settings (intellisense box size and things like that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resize the intellisense box size simply by dragging the lower right corner with the mouse. Just like any other window.

Answer (score 2):

I think all the settings for the intellisense and TextEditor are in

Tools->Options->Text Editor

Comment: Then choose the language and there is an 'Intellisense' section.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2008 you can find the settings for IntelliSense for C# in *Tools | Options... | Text Editor | C# | IntelliSense*.

If this does not work it might be that you have installed another tool that overrides the IntelliSense, like the popular ReSharper. For ReSharper the settings are in *ReSharper | Options... | Environment | IntelliSense*.

Answer (score 1):

By default, most of the IntelliSense options are in effect. You can turn off an option by default and invoke it through a menu command or keystroke combination.

Even when an IntelliSense option is on by default, you can explicitly invoke it. You can also change the default key mappings for each option.

To turn IntelliSense options **off** by default

1. On the Tools menu, click Options.
2. Select the Text Editor folder.
3. Select the folder for the language you want to customize IntelliSense.
4. In the General property page, clear check boxes for IntelliSense features that you do not want:

   - Auto list members applies to List Members
   - Parameter information applies to Parameter Info

In the IntelliSense property page, clear text box options or check box options for IntelliSense features that you do not want:

- Show completion list after a character is typed
- Committed by typing the following characters
- Committed by pressing the space bar
- IntelliSense pre-selects most recently used members applies to IntelliSense for Most Recently Used Members

*Note: If you change the IntelliSense settings, your new settings will apply to IntelliSense in both the Code Editor and the Immediate Mode Command Window.*

For further information there is an page on MSDN: [Using Intellisense](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx)